# EF - Ошибка при попытке добавить запись

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, wcf

Для добавления записи Order в базу использую метод AddOrder:

```
public Order AddOrder(Order order)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var context = new MainDBEntities())
                {
                    context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                    Order ord = context.Order.Add(order); //Здесь проваливается в exception
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    return ord;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                String innerMessage = (ex.InnerException != null)
                      ? ex.InnerException.Message
                      : "";

                return null;
            }
        }
```

Получаю ошибку:

> An item cannot be removed from a fixed size Array of type
>   'MyWCFService.Order[]'.

Класс Order:

```
 [DataContract(IsReference=true)]
    public partial class Order
    {
        public Order()
        {
            this.BSchedule = new HashSet<BSchedule>().ToList();
            this.Sheet = new HashSet<Sheet>().ToList();
        }

        [DataMember]
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public int ServiceID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public int Count { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> AgentID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public System.DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndTime { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public bool isQueued { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public bool isDone { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public double OrgDiscount { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public double IndividualDiscount { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public double TotalPaid { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public double Debt { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public bool isPaid { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public bool isRefunded { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> AgentRoyaltyID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> EmployeeRoyaltyID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public int PaymentType { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
    public virtual Agent Agent { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public virtual AgentRoyalty AgentRoyalty { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public virtual IList<BSchedule> BSchedule { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public virtual EmployeeRoyalty EmployeeRoyalty { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
    public virtual IList<Sheet> Sheet { get; set; }
    }
}
```

В чем может быть причина появления такой ошибки?

**РЕШЕНО:**

Как и подсказывал @cpp_user, проблема заключалась в том, что я использую классы, сгенерированные EF напрямую в службе и клиентах WCF без прокси классов.

Технически, никакого противоречия нет, но на стороне WCF и на стороне клиента получаются совершенно разные экземпляры одного и того же EF класса, хотя внутри он полностью идентичны. Совершенно естественно, что когда я пытаюсь записать в Order любое Relation значение, например Employee, этот Employee на стороне клиента будет таким же, но не тем же самым, что в EF Поэтому в момент записи EF не смогла найти такой экземпляр и выдала странную по своей формулировке ошибку, которую я приводил выше.

В итоге, работающим для меня решением стала перезапрашивание всех привязываемых значений перед записью:

```
  public Order AddOrder(Order order)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var context = new MainDBEntities())
                {
                    context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

                     if (order.Agent != null)
                            order.Agent = context.Agent.First(o => o.AgentID == order.AgentID);

                     if (order.Employee != null)
                         order.Employee = context.Employee.First(o => o.EmployeeID == order.EmployeeID);

                     if (order.Customer != null)
                         order.Customer = context.Customer.First(o => o.CustomerID == order.CustomerID);

                     if (order.Service != null)
                         order.Service = context.Service.First(o => o.ServiceID == order.ServiceID);

                    Order ord = context.Order.Add(order);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    SetUpdateTime("Order");
                    return ord;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                String innerMessage = (ex.InnerException != null)
                      ? ex.InnerException.Message
                      : "";

                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Откуда у вас MyWCFService.Order[]?

Comment: @ cpp_user Да вот неоткуда ему взяться. На английском SO пишут, что такое бывает по двум причинам 1) WCF передает все последовательности в Array - в моем случае это не так: в настройках использую ObservableCollection  2) В классе, описывающем сущность, navigationProperty для коллекций (один ко многим) выражена через ICollection. У меня, как видно в классе Order, выражено через HashSet. Откуда EF берет этот массив и почему пытается удалить что либо из него, когда я ДОБАВЛЯЮ запись - решительно непонятно. Стоит отметить, что через WCF все данные проходят нормально. Проблема определенно в EF.

Comment: Правильнее делать public OrderDTO AddOrder(OrderDTO order) а потом мапить OrderDTO на Order из EF, а так складывается впечатление что вы WCFный Order пытаетесь положить во внутрь EF. P.S. А также нужно иметь разные namespaces для DTO и EF типов.

Comment: @cpp_user Нет никакого "WCFного" Order. В проекте сервиса WCF развернута EF и WCF использует классы EF напрямую без прокси классов. Чтобы классы, сгенерированные EF(DataFirst) нормально сериализовывались и десериализовывались я отредактировал T4.

Comment: В этом собственно ваша ошибка и теперь вы ловите лулзы. ;-)

Comment: А в чем конкретно ошибка? Почему так делать неправильно?

Comment: - типы EF автогенерируются (перегенерация затрет все ваши предыдущие изменения); - структура объектов может меняться в runtime (то что работало вчера может перестать работать сегодня по независящим от вас причинам); - жесткая привязка к EF (заменить на что то другое будет весьма сложно);

Comment: Вот именно поэтому и редактируются файлы t4, чтобы автогенерация была управляемой мною. Я же не вручную все эти [DataContract] и [DataMember] прописываю

Comment: Зачем вам это нужно?

Comment: Потому что меня не устраивает стандартная структура генерируемых EF классов и не хочется каждый раз после регенерации вносить одни и те же изменения в двух дюжинах классов.

Comment: Но в этом случае все ваши ошибки отловятся на этапе компиляции, а так будете ловить лулзы в рантайме неизвестно где и неизвестно когда.

Comment: @cpp_user, вы были правы! Добавил решение к вопросу. Пожалуйста, преобразуйте свой комментарий в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я предлагал нечто подобное:

```
public OrderDTO AddOrder(OrderDTO order_dto)
{
    try
    {
        using (var context = new ClinicMainDBEntities())
        {
            Order order = new Order();
            if (order != null)
            {
                order = Mapper.DynamicMap<Order>(order_dto);
                OrderDTO new_order = Mapper.DynamicMap<OrderDTO>(context.Order.Add(order));
                context.SaveChanges();
                return new_order;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        String innerMessage = (ex.InnerException != null)
            ? ex.InnerException.Message
            : "";
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Да, так намного короче